# Apache Camel : Read Values from Configuration File and Exchange Property altogether

Tags: apache-camel

I am implementing a dynamic toD, where-in I want to send data to rabbit MQ using dynamic values at RunTime.

The Value of : `${exchangeProperty.erpFlow} = user.create`

Approach :

```
<toD uri="rabbitmq:${properties:rabbit.uri.${exchangeProperty.erpFlow}}"/>
```

Configuration File Looks like:

```
rabbit:
 uri:
  user:
   create: "${rabbit.exchanges.customersDead}?${rabbit.exchangeArgs}&${rabbit.queueName}=org.user.create&concurrentConsumers=${rabbit.dlqConcurrentConsumers}&skipQueueDeclare=false"
```

at RunTime, I am expecting the dynamic toD to look like,

```
<toD uri="rabbitmq:MyExchange?exchangeType=topic&bridgeEndpoint=true&queue=org.user.create&concurrentConsumers=2&skipQueueDeclare=false"/>
```

Expectation : At runtime, the values should be read from both configuration file and exchange Property.

Error I see :

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: rabbitmq:{{rabbit.uri.${exchangeProperty.erpFlow}}} due to: Property with key [rabbit.uri.${exchangeProperty.erpFlow] not found in properties from text: rabbitmq:{{rabbit.uri.${exchangeProperty.erpFlow}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem here is due to `exchangeProperty` field, as property placeholders are instantiated during runtime. Exchange properties only exist when a camel exchange has been instantiated - meaning that property will only contain value if a message has been sent in the route producer.

[Here](https://camel.apache.org/components/4.4.x/properties-component.html) are some information on how `properties` are loaded to camel if you are not using other frameworks.

Your best case solution here is to replace `exchangeProperty.erpFlow` with an env var or just put it in the config properties file as well.